# Identity Server 4 Post Logout URL Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-authentication

I'm having some issues trying to figure out how to get the post logout URL working in my ASP.NET Core MVC application. I have been following examples from the Identity Server documentation and other posts, though I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong. The user is successfully logged out of the application, then redirected to Identity Server and logged out there, but I notice that the id_token parameter is not being passed to Identity Server, so even though the post logout parameter is present, it's not being used.

My middleware config looks correct, I feel it's an issue with how I'm creating the application cookie and the token is not really being saved anywhere where it can be re-used.

I'm currently only using the "code" response type, but this does seem to also include an identity token along with the authorization token.

**Startup.cs:**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerSettings:AuthorityUrl"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Audience = Configuration["IdentityServerSettings:Audience"];
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerSettings:AuthorityUrl"];
                options.ClientId = "myClient";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:55690/account/logoutcallback";
                options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/account/logoutcallback";
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });
```

**AccountController.cs**

Logout methods:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        return new SignOutResult(new[] { CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "oidc" });
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> LogoutCallback()
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Dashboard), "Account");
    }
```

Login callback:

```
if (!Request.Query.ContainsKey("code"))
                throw new Exception($"Request query string does not contain an authorization code. Query string: {Request.QueryString.Value}");

            var authCode = Request.Query["code"].ToString();

            TokenResponse tokenResponse = null;
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                tokenResponse = await httpClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
                {
                    Address = _configuration["IdentityServerDashboardSettings:TokenUrl"],
                    ClientId = _configuration["IdentityServerDashboardSettings:ClientId"],
                    RedirectUri = _configuration["IdentityServerDashboardSettings:RedirectUrl"],
                    Code = authCode
                });
            }

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtToken = handler.ReadToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken) as JwtSecurityToken;

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwtToken.Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", tokenResponse.IdentityToken));

            var claimsPrinciple = new ClaimsPrincipal();
            claimsPrinciple.AddIdentity(identity);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrinciple);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Dashboard), "Account");
```

Everything else works fine, SignOutResult successfully constructs the logout URL and redirects to Identity Server, but it's missing the id_token in the parameters. I can't really find any examples on how I'm supposed to store this for later use, a lot of examples I've came across seem to just work automatically. Is there something I've configured wrong?

Comment: are you looking to have custom logout redirect path?

Comment: Yes, I more or less just want to redirect the user back to the application and onto the account page where they can log in again, but currently after logout they're just left on an Identity Server page.

Comment: I see, left the answer as it was so long for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect back to MVC client, make following changes:

1. Change `PostLogoutRedirectUris` on Client's config within IdentityServer to be like this:

```
PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:55690/signout-callback-oidc"
```

2. On MVC client's OpenId connect setup remove `SignedOutRedirectUri` and `SignedOutCallbackPath`

The default value for `AccountOptions` - `AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut` is false and you may see a page like image bellow, asking to click on `here` to get back to mvc client:

[image]

for automatic redirect you can set `AccountOptions` - `AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut` to true on IdentityServer project.

[Here](https://github.com/nahidf-adventures/IdentityServer4-adventures/blob/ids4-4/src/MvcClient/Startup.cs) is a sample I did myself.

Comment: Thanks, this solved part of my issue. I also found out since we host our own instance of Identity Server, someone had also disabled the automatic redirect logic in Identity Server itself, so once that was restored it's now successfully working and solved the other part.